# Adding style change to DIV inside ajax function...?

Tags: javascript, html, styles

I have a much larger javascript with some ajax that basically checks for a condition, on success:

`success: function(){
    document.getElementById('res-cancel-message').style.color = "#008000";
    $("#res-cancel-message").html('<a>Your reservation has been cancelled and a confirmation has been sent to your email address.</a>');`

Currently this script changes the color of the res-cancel-message div and then populates it with some text.  What I am trying to do is change the size of the text as well, to 10pt.  Unfortunately I have tried all kinds of simple style changes such as the color change I used in the above code, to no avail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you tried using:

```
document.getElementById('res-cancel-message').style.font-size = 'something';
```

It wont work, you need to remove `-` and capitalize the first letter of following word like this:

```
document.getElementById('res-cancel-message').style.fontSize = '10pt';
```